# Как в Retrofit 2 передать динамический параметр. Метод Get

Tags: android, retrofit2

Иметься хостинг, который в качестве ответа генерирует json.

> http:// example.com/get-json/getJsonPosts.php?2

где ?2 - id поста.

У меня не получается в `@Get` передать параметр.

```
interface Api {

    @GET("getJsonPosts.php?{id}")
    fun loadtPost(@Path("id") groupId: Int): Observable<ArrayList<Card>>
}
```

Реализация

```
override fun uploadData() {

   var api : Api?  = null
   api = MyApplication().connectServer()
   api!!.loadtPost(10) // Передаю параметр
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({ e ->
            recyclerView.adapter!!.notifyItemInserted(cards.size - 1)
            for (i in 0 until e.size) {
                cards.add(Card(e[i].photoUrl,
                                e[i].title,
                                e[i].date,
                                e[i].description,
                                e[i].photoUrl,
                                e[i].likeCaunt))
          }
      })

    }
```

Получаю ошибку

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "{id}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.
```

Пробую теперь так

interface Api {

```
    @GET("getJsonPosts.php?")
    fun loadtPost(@Query("") groupId: Int): Observable<ArrayList<Card>>
}
```

Получаю ошибку

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Возможно мне нужно запрос реализовать так:

> http:// example.com/get-json/getJsonPosts.php?id=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Отредактировал пост 06.06.18**

Оказалось что нужно было принимать url запрос на сервере вот такой.

> http:// example.com/get-json/getJsonPosts.php?id=2

Ранее я на сервере обрабатывал этот url адрес для получения json.

> http:// example.com/get-json/getJsonPosts.php?2

Теперь в `@Get` можно подставлять динамические параметры таким образом. Ранее я делал по другому, см. в задаваемом вопросе.

```
interface Api {    
    @GET("getJsonPosts.php")
    fun loadtPost( @Query("id") id : Int): Observable<ArrayList<Card>>
}
```

**Как это работает**

1. Аннотация @GET не только отправит GET запрос, но и к `.baseUrl` добавит ***getJsonPosts.php***.
2. Аннотация @Query к генерируемому запросу @GET **сама** добавить **?** и слово **id** которое указано @Query("id <- ***здесь*** ") и подставит в конец знак **=** 2, где 2, это передаваемый параметр. Результат *http:// example.com/get-json/getJsonPosts.php?id=2*

   Базовый url

   ```
   fun connectServer() : Api? {
   val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
           .baseUrl("http://example.com/get-json/") // БАЗОВЫЙ URL.
           .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
           .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
           .build()

   return retrofit.create(Api::class.java)
   ```

   }

**Узнал больше**

На самом сайте нет подробной информации об использовании аннотаций. Чтобы узнать как работает конкретная аннотация, наведите курсор на аннотацию, кликнете мышью и нажмите F4 (Windows). Вам откроются исходники, в комментариях вы найдете как она работает и какой url она сможет сгенерировать.

Если я вам помог, жмите на стрелку вверх

Comment: помог, только как объяснил трудно;)

Comment: Добрый день, я могу отредактировать ответ, если вы укажите причину, трудности понимания ответа.