# Помощь по API Retrofit

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit

Прохожу на собеседование на Junior Android, был выдан файл

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: 3.0.0
  title: Unreal Mojo Super-Duper Hamsters API
  description: |
    #### A terrific API for hamsters querying

schemes:
  - http

host: unrealmojo.com
basePath: /porn
produces:
  - application/json
consumes:
  - application/json

paths:
  /test3:
    get:
      description: Querying endpoint, blows your mind with the wonderful world of hamsters
      parameters:
        - name: X-Homo-Client-OS
          in: header
          type: string
          required: true
          description: Mobile OS name and version. For example - Android 4.3.3
        - name: X-Homo-Client-Version
          in: header
          type: string
          required: true
          description: App name and version number. For example - HomoTestApp 1.0
        - name: X-Homo-Client-Model
          in: header
          type: string
          required: true
          description: Mobile device manufacturer name and model. For example - Samsung GalaxyTab 7

      responses:
        200:
          description: Hamsters list for you
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/HamsterModel'
        500:
          description: On any unexpected error. Normally this endpoint should not produce any expected error.

definitions:
  HamsterModel:
    type: object
    properties:
      title:
        type: string
        description: Hamster name
      desc:
        type: string
        description: Long detailed descriptions of the hamster
      pinned:
        type: boolean
        description: This flag indicates the importance of this hamster
      image:
        type: string
        description: Complete url to a hamster full size photo. Not every hamster has a photo.
```

Вопросы:

1. почему ответ не совпадает с моделью? `https://unrealmojo.com/porn/test3/` отсутствуют поля desc и pinned. Или они не обязательны?
2. Как составить правильно get запрос в retrofit 2? Точнее какие параметры нужно передать? как я понял необходимо передовать номер версии Android, название проекта и название модели телефона, только я не уверен, что нужно передавать в Get, возможно их нужно указать в headerе запроса, если да, то скиньте пример как

Пример, как я отправляю запросы:

```
interface ApiService{
    @GET("test3")
    fun getTopHeadlines(): Single<Result>

    companion object Factory {

        fun create(): ApiService {
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl(APIUrl.baseUrl)
                    .build()

            return retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, проверьте этот пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/801170/Как-в-retrofit-2-передать-динамический-параметр-Метод-get/801509#801509

Comment: Возьмите любой Swagger UI, откройте свое задание и сделайте пару запросов, все станет понятней. Это возможно одна из скрытых проверок, насколько вы понимаете что есть и зачем Swagger.